# How to Zoom CollectionviewCell Image when it was Selected?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

i make an application that conatin UICollectionview with CustumCell and each Cell Contain images i want to make when any image selected then it was zoom in view and when zoom view touch 
then collectionview was Shown like as a URBMediaFocusViewController Libraray

link of library is here [URBMediaFocusViewController](https://github.com/u10int/URBMediaFocusViewController)

i know it was asked many times but please give me solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very elegant, but this is how I do it. Basically get the frame location and size of your source UICollectionView Cell, the frame and location of where you want it to appear (in this case I fill the view), then animate between the two sizes. Hope this helps.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    [collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally];

   [self zoomToSelectedImage:indexPath];

}


-(void)zoomToSelectedImage:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    UIImageView *zoomImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self.myPictures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

zoomImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

CGRect zoomFrameTo = CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);

UICollectionView *cv = (UICollectionView *)[self.view viewWithTag:66]; // Change to whatever the tag value of your collectionView is 

cv.hidden = TRUE;

UICollectionViewCell *cellToZoom =(UICollectionViewCell *)[cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

CGRect zoomFrameFrom = cellToZoom.frame;

[self.view addSubview:zoomImage];

zoomImage.frame = zoomFrameFrom;

zoomImage.alpha = 0.2;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:

^{

     zoomImage.frame = zoomFrameTo;

     zoomImage.alpha = 1;

 } completion:nil];
```

Comment: i make this code for my apps but it was not working my code is
-(void)zoomToSelectedImage:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [self.imagesa objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    NSString *img=[dict valueForKey:@"link"];
    UIImageView *zoomImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:img]];

Comment: #Gismay I solved it but when i zoom an image then background Collectionview is also shown i want to hide him and when user click on zoomed image then it was back in to collection view any solution for that?

Comment: Just set the hidden flag of your UICollectionView to TRUE to hide it, then set it back when you've finished. Add a tap gesture regcogniser to detect when the user had tapped on the image.

Comment: How to set hidden flag of UICollectionView to TRUE? Please give me  code for that???

Comment: Add a tag to your UICollectionView in interface builder. Then use the method I have used in my example; UICollectionView *cv = (UICollectionView *)[self.view viewWithTag:what ever your tag is]; 

cv.hidden = TRUE;

Comment: i write a code at your UICollectionView *cv = (UICollectionView *)[self.view viewWithTag:what ever your tag is] replace it with 
self.imagecollection = (UICollectionView *)[self.view viewWithTag:66];
    self.imagecollection.hidden = TRUE;
    UICollectionViewCell *cellToZoom =(UICollectionViewCell *)[self.imagecollection cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
But it was not working. same as a above

Comment: Did you add the tag in interface builder to your collectionView?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63834/discussion-between-ashish-gabani-and-gismay).

Comment: #Gismay my image was Zommed but now i wnat to back when touch outside of image how it was possible??Please Give me solution